# Setting up EmberJS project directory structure?

Tags: ember.js

I have been working with EmberJS online guides, and it has been somewhat of a hit or miss process. With Sproutcore2 I could generate the project directory structure via commandline command and be done with it. Well with Ember, it is rather manual. I would like to be able to set up a project's director structure where I am able to separate the model(s),view(s), and control(s) into their own folders. I have been trying to do so but require statements aren't importing correctly from MVC folders. I have downloaded the "todos" app, but it is no help, because the directory structure is not demonstrated as I had expected.

I would like to start with a simple "HelloWorld" application where "app" will be my facade, and I can then import my models,views, and controls from their folders which will be placed under mvc folder within the "HelloWorldApp" folder. Appreciate all your help.

**HelloWorldApp (project directory)**
   ->js (directory)
   ->lib (directory)
            ->ember-0.9.5
            ->ember-0.9.5.min
            ->jquery-1.6.1.min
       
  ->template (directory)
          ->main-view-template
  ->mvc (directory)
              ->model (directory)
              ->view (directory)
              ->control (directory)
  ->css (directory)
app (app.js)
index.htm

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After trying out different approaches, I ended up declaring all my model(s), views(s), and controller(s) in the index file right after where the ember-0.9.5 is being called via javascript. Once I did that I was able to instantiate my model "Person" in "app".

Thx.

Comment: Oh no that's going to be horrible for a large app. You can declare them in folders under the `app/lib` directory. Just don't forget to use `require()` to make sure everything is built in the correct order.

Comment: Roy, did that and then tried other ways. It doesn't work by declaring them in in folders under "app/lib". If you go over my question, I had stated that "require" statement is not importing the "packages/namespaces". And I agree with you...by including them into the index file is a horrible way.

Comment: Combustion, I'm curious if you've found a better way to do this now. If you have, would you mind posting more about it? I'm just getting started with ember (and web applications in general), and it's a lot to swallow at once -- any information is appreciated.

Comment: @iX3, none other approaches were success. I am still employing my original findings which I have mentioned above. Thx

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the early alpha of the Ember build tools' template structure (based on [Ember-Skeleton](https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton)): https://github.com/emberjs/ember-gem/tree/master/lib/ember/templates/app. I'd imagine that something very close to this structure will be the default moving forward.

Comment: Roy,thank u for the link, I have spent a good chunk of my day going through this resource, now I am trying to figure out where the facade is buried in all this code. It would have been nice to have some sort of demonstration available on EmberJS online documentation.

Comment: When the app is created a global property, `App.stateManager`, is also created. It has an initial start state, `App.StartState`, which is a ViewState. ViewStates are like normal states, except it has the extra feature that when you enter and exit a ViewState it will automatically append any `Ember.View` that is defined on it's `view` property. So in the above template the view property has a view defined with a template, `main_page`. That template holds the initial template shown. If you need to run any code at startup, in main.js add `MyApp.ready = function() {//..init code goes here...}`

Comment: Roy, thanks a lot for the explanation. Before your last comment, I didn't even know anything about "states". However, I do know how "states" function, I have a long history with "Adobe Flex". I gotta ask you this, why isn't there any mention of "states" or any demo code on EmberJs online documentation? I think it is rather a poor way to introduce a framework without proper online documentation whether it is or isn't an open-source effort? Now regards to what you shared in your last comment, would it be possible for you to "jsfiddle" some code so I can get an idea.

Comment: I would highly appreciate it if you can demo how can I go about including the (model,view,control) namespace into my facade/app and get going with it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Combustion...just FYI, a new website is coming soon from the Ember folks. For now, you can also references the API docs: http://ember-docs.herokuapp.com/ They're not currently linked from the website, but I've submitted a pull request to add it in: https://github.com/emberjs/website/pull/58

Comment: @Combustion007 I'm not quite sure I understand what you'd like me to show you... Could you maybe rephrase/elaborate on what you need help with?

Comment: After spending 5 days trying to setup directory structure so I can have models, views, and controllers in their own folders, I have solved it and have also concluded that EmberJS maybe a good framework, but it is still a wild wild west even the online documentation is incomplete. I come from frameworks such as "PUREMVC", and "ROBOTLEGS", and am not a newbie when it comes to object oriented code. I can only speak for myself, and if it will require hours and hours for me to find out just the simplest things to get going with a new framework then I am not being very productive.

Comment: @Combustion007 i second your thoughts, i have the exact same problems coming from working with CakePHP and Robotlegs. Templates vs Views is confusing and not having a good starting point with a defined folder structure and default routing is really annyoing. But im still very interested in working with ember though i can't seem to get past this initial steps.